Multiplicity between classes in class diagram
I want to describe relationship between User and Party using UML class diagram. The relationship is:

A user can only belong to 1 Party (User 1 ————— 1 Party)
A party can have multiple users (User 0..* ————— 1 Party)

So which multiplicity should we use? Should we use 2 lines to describe the relationships between them?
And another question is that: should we use an arrow instead of a line to describe this relationship?

"A user can only belong to 1 Party" - since “can”, it’s not 1, but 0..1

Each of these sentences defines the multiplicity only on one side.  With two sentences you have the multiplicities on both sides:

A user can only belong to attend 1 Party


This does only set the constraint for the number of parties a user can attend. It does not say anything about how many users could attend the party.


A party can have be attended by multiple users


This does only set the constraint for the number of users attending a party, but says nothing about how many parties a user can attend.

I have slightly reworded the two sentences to disambiguate the association. In this simple example, it's obvious that the two sentences are about the same association. But in the real world you can have situations were two sentences only say half the truth about two different associations.
To disambiguate further you could even specify "at one precise moment in time". Because users can usually attend plenty of parties in their lives, just not at the same time.
